# How to get the text for Tree in reverse way

Tags: stanford-nlp

Please, Could anybody help me in order to extract the text from a Tree??

e.g. : (NP (NP (DT the) (JJ main) (NN road)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Rontau))))

The text : "the main road of Rontau"

I'm using stanford trees package.

Answer (score 0):

You want the "yield" of a parse tree. You can access this as a list of `Label` instances using the method [`Tree#yield`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/).